# Is Swift for iOS identical to Swift for Mac?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swift, ios-simulator

I would like to know is Swift universal for Mac and iOS.

If it's not identical, what are the main difference?

Can a Swift iOS developer develop Mac apps without learning it all over again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Swift is a language. The swift language will be the same for when you are making IOS apps or Mac applications. When you are making an ios app you are using alot of libraries and framework that help you do things that you would need. So when you try making the Mac applications you will not have access to those same framework and libraries. You would need to learn new ones. It would not take a lot of effort to go from an ios developer to building Mac applications.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @the_pickle, Swift is a language. A language is platform-independent.

iOS and Mac OS are two platforms. They have their own set of frameworks and libraries. As Wikipedia puts it:

> A software framework is an abstraction in which software providing
>   generic functionality can be selectively changed by additional
>   user-written code, thus providing application-specific software. A
>   software framework is a universal, reusable software environment that
>   provides particular functionality as part of a larger software
>   platform to facilitate development of software applications, products
>   and solutions. Software frameworks may include support programs,
>   compilers, code libraries, tool sets, and application programming
>   interfaces (APIs) that bring together all the different components to
>   enable development of a project or solution.

What this means is that a framework makes it easy by providing something generic, say a blank view. What the programmer does is use that view and modify it to fit the needs of the software they are making. So they can make that view green, rounded at the corners, semi-transparent, and/or a combination of many other possibilities.

That is where iOS and Mac OS differ. They have their own set of frameworks and libraries. They are nothing but a bunch of stuff that is needed by programmers over and over again. So they make it reusable in the form of a framework, and allow you to customize it.

However, the language (Swift) is still the same. So that means you will call functions, declare and use variables and everything else in the same way.

If you are trying to be an iOS developer, you will need to learn the (general) language Swift, and the (specific) iOS frameworks. If you are trying to be a Mac developer, then you will have to learn the (general) language Swift, and the (specific) Mac frameworks.

Here's a good starting point for you:
Learn about Swift from here:
https://developer.apple.com/swift/resources/
This is a good starting document:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html

Learn about iOS frameworks starting here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/iPhoneOSFrameworks/iPhoneOSFrameworks.html

Learn about Mac frameworks starting here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/OSX_Technology_Overview/SystemFrameworks/SystemFrameworks.html

And then get started on learning about putting it all in practice from any online course. Here's a course that takes it easy and is available for free as of now:
https://www.bitfountain.io/

Comment: Thanks everyone! This seriously helped me! Thanks!!